# Transact SQL: Synchronization of Views to Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have written the following code to do a comparision of a View and its corresponding production table. I am looking for better ways to write this code for efficiency, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. The code gives me the desired results, Now it's just a point of learning new approaches and concepts to it.

http://pastebin.com/pSTdCx3L

Comment: Asking for broad opinions on refactoring your code isn't the best way to get answers. Try pointing to specific places in the code you're unhappy, explain why, what you've tried to improve them, and so on...

Comment: Otherwise you could ask your question on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is a more appropriate place for enhancing the code. (StackOverflow is more about solving problems with the code.)

Comment: Efficiency is do it properly. Lordy, what overkill. Next time, ask here on SO *before* rather than *after*. Then we can help *solve your problem* rather than *close your non-SO question*

Answer (score 2):

If you declare your view [WITH SCHEMABINDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), you don't need this overhead.

I always use it. It disallows changes to base table used in the view (or udf).
It also forces columns to be qualified and to use 2 part object names.

> SCHEMABINDING
>
> Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified.

Although, you asked for a review, I am quite amused (read: "[facepalm](http://i.imagehost.org/0439/3414_Tactical_facepalm_jpg-550x0.jpg)") by:

- your dynamic ALTER VIEW when you could just run "[sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx)" or [sp_refreshsqlmodule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx)
- your one to one table to view mapping. Why? It adds no value